# Mathematics: A Spectacular Sport. Are there (unscripted) vlogs of people actually doing mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, recreational-mathematics, online-resources

> Are there vlogs of people regularly *attempting* to solve mathematics problems, warts & all?

I haven't found any.

I know of puzzle-attempt YouTube channels, like  [CanChrisSolve?](https://m.youtube.com/user/haribo41296), so why aren't there mathematics problem solving vlogs?

What I'm *not* looking for are channels like [LetsSolveMathProblems](https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCEI9wNw9a4cJfejeAU6J2wQ); such channels are great but they're too scripted, focusing on the finished product rather than the process of solving a mathematical problem.

I want to see the mistakes, the experiments, the dead ends; swearing, blaspheming, gesticulating; the banging of heads against walls and the *a-ha!* moments of fleeting insight. I want a stream of consciousness.

"Solving a good mathematics problem could take weeks or even months of effort," I hear you object. That's no obstacle, though, really, since ongoing projects from elsewhere, like [Wintergatan's](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wintergatan) Marble Machine X, have strong followings and considerable longevity. There's practically nothing a little montage can't fix.

A hypothetical example of how an episode might start would be something like this:

> Hi, so today I'm going to try & prove that the product of $n$ consecutive integers is always divisible by $n!$. Let's jump straight into it.
>
> Okay, so, my initial thoughts are that it has something to do with how multiples of $k$ for each $k$ from $1$ to $n$ are . . . Erm . . . "distributed". There's a multiple of $k$ every $k$ integers, so $n$ consecutive integers must have a multiple of $k$ for a given $k$ from $1$ to $n$, right? Right.
>
> But there's a tricky issue of whether or not one counts such a multiple twice in the factorial. For instance, in $4\times 5\times 6$, divisible by $3!$, we have that $6$ is both a multiple of $2$ and a multiple of $3$, but there's another multiple of $2$ - namely, $4$ - and what I need to do . . . I think . . . is to show that there's always a number, like $4$, that's a . . . Erm . . . "sensible alternative" to some other number, like $6$, or that the overlap doesn't matter. Does that make sense? I'm not sure.
>
> F¥¢k.

You get the idea: each episode a soliloquy of problem solving, filmed.

Comment: I'm sure there are some professional mathematicians who would be willing to start Twitch streams if someone asked them :) Whether they're planning class lectures, or working on their own research, it would be a cool to watch them work and talk through what they're doing.

Comment: Why not go HUGE and stream a reality show of a mathematician, or the professors in a math department at, say MAT University, and show their day to day lives in lectures, during office hours, in seminars, their research, and let's not forget, their committee work ... day by day...